# Days in UTC to days in local time zone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have an array of days
eg :

```
days_of_week: ["SUNDAY", "TUESDAY", "THURSDAY"]
hours : 19 
minute : 30
```

this array denotes the days in UTC timezone.

I want to display the array of days in local timezone.

So, the above example would look like (at IST (UTC+5:30))

```
days : Mon, Wed, Fri
hrs : 01
min : 00
```

I can convert the time but I'm not able to figure out the offset calculation for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a relatively simple function that will calculate the desired offsets, both in time and days.

NB: This will only work for fixed timezone offsets. IST will work because there's currently no daylight savings time. This wouldn't work for, say Pacific Time or Western European Time.

```js
let all_days_of_week = ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY"];

days_of_week = ["SUNDAY", "TUESDAY", "THURSDAY"]
hours = 19 
minute = 30;

function getOffsetTimes(hour, minutes, fixedOffsetMinutes, daysOfWeek) {

    let time = hour*60 + minutes;
    let offsetTime = time + fixedOffsetMinutes;
    let offsetDays = 0;
    if (offsetTime >= 1440) {
        offsetDays++;
        offsetTime = offsetTime % 1440;
    }
    
    let newDaysOfWeek = daysOfWeek.map((d, i) => (all_days_of_week.findIndex(dow => dow === d) + offsetDays) % 7 ).map(n => all_days_of_week[n]);
    
    return { hour: Math.floor(offsetTime/60), minute: (offsetTime % 60), daysOfWeek:  newDaysOfWeek}
}

console.log(getOffsetTimes(19, 30, 330, ["SUNDAY", "TUESDAY", "THURSDAY"]));
```